# Как найти количество строк текста на си шарп

Tags: c#

Как найти количество строк текста на си шарп, после загрузки файла на перемены string? Можно ли найти с помощью спецсимволы '\n'. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: var countStrok = text.Split('\n').Count();

Comment: Если вы подразумеваете подсчёт строк в файле то можно просто File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Count

Comment: Задача вот такой данной слова в каком строке находится в тексте type string

Comment: Всё получилось, всем спасибо.